# JQuery Security Issue - Link manipulation (DOM-based)

Tags: jquery

There is Link manipulation (DOM-based) issue identified by BURP suite against
/jquery-3.3.1.js

The problem is in the code:

// Anchor tag for parsing the document origin

originAnchor = document.createElement( "a" );

**originAnchor.href = location.href;**

Could anyone comment if the issue is false positive or not. 
The issue remains in the newest version of the library too.

Thanks

Comment: And one more place with the issue:
           // Set the base href for the created document
           // so any parsed elements with URLs
           // are based on the document's URL (gh-2965)
           base = context.createElement( "base" );
           base.href = document.location.href;
           context.head.appendChild( base );
       } else {
           context = document;
       }


Data is read from document.location.href and passed to the 'href' property of a DOM element via the following statement:
base.href = document.location.href;

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer from Burp support:

'I don’t see any significant security impact from either of those, so yes, they are false positives.

The JavaScript analysis within Burp is very thorough, but unfortunately does produce some false positives.'

https://support.portswigger.net/customer/en/portal/questions/17491027-link-manipulation-dom-based-jquery?new=17491027

The findings are false positive.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22015452)

Comment: Done. Thank you. But the answer from support team is not detailed at all. )